# Fuzzy match ranking

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I fuzzy matched a list of movie titles and compiled them into another list of each comparison along with the match values:

```
>>> fuzzy_matches
[(['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], 100), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Digiview Entertainment)'], 63), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Platinum)'], 78), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Platinum) / David And Goliath'], 63), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Platinum) / Duel Of Champions'], 61)]...etc
```

I want to add up the match values for each title so that I get output like this:

```
>>>([White Warrior (Alpha Video)], 248),
['White Warrior 2 (Digiview Entertainment)'], 390),
etc...
```

I have tried several implementations utilizing slices but it's ugly.

(Not my exact code but this is the ugliness):

```
for x in range(len(fuzzed)):
    for y in fuzzed(len(fuzzed)):

big_dict[fuzzy_matches[55][0][0]]=fuzzy_matches[55][2] + fuzzy_matches[56][3]...
```

what is a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just to confirm, the second item in the first 6 lines have quotes outside the brackets, while the next 6 don't, correct?

Comment: yes, not sure why my list comp is doing that, but I find that it hasn't affected my output

Comment: Can you just print the list, and give the output in the question?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I don't understand your question

Comment: Fuzzy_matches list , can you print it, the one you posted above does not look like a single valid list

Comment: @AnandSKumar edited to show exact output. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict to store the results you want , and then at the end if you want a list of tuples , you can use `dict.items()` (Python 3.x ) to get that.

Example -

```
>>> fuzzy_matches = [(['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], 100), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Digiview Entertainment)'], 63), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Platinum)'], 78), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Platinum) / David And Goliath'], 63), (['White Warrior (Alpha Video)'], ['White Warrior (Platinum) / Du
el Of Champions'], 61)]
>>>
>>> fuzzy_dict = {}
>>> for i in fuzzy_matches:
...     if i[0][0] not in fuzzy_dict:
...             fuzzy_dict[i[0][0]] = 0
...     fuzzy_dict[i[0][0]] += i[2]
...
>>> fuzzy_dict
{'White Warrior (Alpha Video)': 365}
>>> list(fuzzy_dict.items())
[('White Warrior (Alpha Video)', 365)]
```

You do not need `list(...)` at the end if you are using Python 2.x .

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you- I hope many more people see your solution and realize the value it holds in ranking fuzzy matches